# how to deserialize json into objects in c#

Tags: c#, json, vk

could not deserialize json into objects. try to use *DataContractJsonSerializer*. 
here is how i use it
 have NO idea how to cope with it..
**CLASS**

```
    [Serializable]
    public class user
    {
        public user() { }
        public user(string _uid, string _first_name, string _last_name, string _online)
        {
            this._uid = _uid;
            this._first_name = _first_name;
            this._last_name = _last_name;
            this._online = _online;
        }

        string _uid;
        string _first_name;
        string _last_name;
        string _online;

        [DataMember]
        public string uid
        {
            get { return _uid; }
            set { _uid = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string first_name
        {
            get { return _first_name; }
            set { _first_name = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string last_name
        {
            get { return _last_name; }
            set { _last_name = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string online
        {
            get { return _online; }
            set { _online = value; }
        }
    }
```

**DataContractJsonSerializer Usage**

```
        WebRequest w = WebRequest.Create(string.Format("https://api.vk.com/method/friends.get?uid=6631031&fields=uid,first_name,last_name&access_token={0}",_accesstoken));
        Stream stream = w.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();

        //StreamReader sread = new StreamReader(stream);//here i can get the result into a string
        //string sLine = sread.ReadLine();              //to make sure the result is valid json

        DataContractJsonSerializer json = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(user[]));
        var result = (user[]) json.ReadObject(stream);
```

**EXAMPLE OF MY JSON**

```
"{\"response\":[{\"uid\":779358,\"first_name\":\"Dark\",\"last_name\":\"Knight\",\"online\":0},{\"uid\":1023931,\"first_name\":\"Екатерина\",\"last_name\":\"Гаврилова\",\"online\":0},{\"uid\":2475856,\"first_name\":\"Даша\",\"last_name\":\"Матвеева\",\"online\":0},......]}"
```

Comment: Duplicate Question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a wrapper object containing a `response` property of type `user[]` in order to reflect your JSON structure:

```
[DataContract]
public class Result
{
    [DataMember]
    public user[] response { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
DataContractJsonSerializer json = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Result));
Result result = (Result)json.ReadObject(stream);
user[] users = result.response;
```

Comment: @Dimitrov, i've tried this. at the line                          Result result = (Result)json.ReadObject(stream); there is an exception SerializationException. Type of data contract "wpfapp3.mainwindow+user" cannot be deserialized, as it is impossible to find all necessary data elements "_first_name, _last_name, _online, _uid". sorry for translation of description

Comment: @user1200752, here are a few things to try. Move this `user` class declaration into a separate file so that it is not nested inside the MainWindow class. Then decorate it with the `[DataContract]` attribute and remove the `[Serializable]` attribute.

Comment: @Dimitrov, were you've been several days ago!? thank you so much! you've helped me so much!!!!!<br> ps.just decorated User class with [DataContract]